# Diferencia entre Componente y Elemento de React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy estudiando React sin embargo aún no me queda claro cuál es la diferencia entre un Elemento y un Componente de React, claro que he leído la teoría y he practicado los ejercicios del curso sin embargo siento que aún no puedo identificarlos del todo y la verdad no quiero errar al momento de explicarle  a mis compañeros en el trabajo.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con esta duda?

Answer (score 3):

**Actualización Jan, 2024**

Es confuso, pero lo siguiente puede ayudar:

***React Component.***

- Es un contenedor que puede configurarse con diferentes opciones como state, props, context, children, statics y stateless components.
- Cuando define mutabilidad de estado (state changes), se le llama Statefull Component.
- Cuando no define mutabilidad de estado, se le llama Stateless Component (componentes re-utilizables), solo usa el método `return` y normalmente es un contenedor de Elementos React.
- Se declara con `createReactClass`, ES6 Class o como una función JS.

***React Element***

- Es la representación virtual de un elemento HTML, esta representación se conoce como virtual DOM.
- Se puede crear con el método `React.createElement(tag)`, o directamente con JSX.
- Su contenedor es un Satetless component
- Se puede agrupar cierto numero de React Elements dentro del método `return`.
- Un Componente en react también es un React Element.

Con la introducción de los **React Hooks**, están surgiendo nuevos patrones al códificar componentes ReactJs, al parecer el uso de ES6 Class sintax, se está remplanzando por **simples funciones JS**.

Aquí el enlace con un ejemplo el Hook `useState`:

[Uso básico de Hook useState](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380902/peticiones-react-js-hooks/380918#380918)

Al analizar los nuevos patrones ReactJs con sintáxis Class/function, para identificar si estamos ante un *Componente Statefull o Stateless*, **debemos buscar si se define estado**; si se define estado, entonces estamos ante un **Statefull Component**, si no define estado es un **Stateless Component** (re-utilizable).

En el siguiente video, se explica de forma muy clara el uso básico de los React Hooks:

[Hooks React Conf 2018](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM)

En este artículo, se explican las diferencias entre Class/function:

[Class vs function React](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/)

[React Component vs React Element](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b7yQ2bed0o)

Saludos