# Problema para obtener información de una API utilizando promesas en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, poo, async-await

estoy haciendo una petición a una API , utilizando promesas async await , el problema sucede luego de que traigo la información de la API , ya que en consola  puedo observar la información de manera correcta pero luego cuando selecciono una propiedad del objeto que contiene toda la informacion traida de la API , su valor pasa a ser undefined.

peticion

```
export let GetPoke = async () =>{
  try{
let res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu');
let data = await res.json();
let obj = {
  img : data.sprites.front_default,
  habilidad: data.abilities[0]
}
return obj ;
}
catch(err){
  throw ("ah ocurrido un error" + err);

}


}
```

Luego llamo a la funcion en mi componente:

```
function Home(){

  let datespoke = GetPoke();
  console.log(datespoke); //informacion 
  console.log(datespoke.img); //undefined
  
    return (
      <>
      <h1>Bienvenidos</h1>
     
      </>
    );

}
```

el resultado de datespoke que muestra en consola es este :

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
habilidad: {ability: {…}, is_hidden: false, slot: 1}
img: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/25.png"
__proto__: Object
```

Sin embargo datespoke.img es UNDEFINED.

Soy nuevo en react y aparentemente me estoy equivocando al traerme los objetos , espero que alguno me pueda ayudar gracias.

Comment: lo que debe estar pasando es que la funcion es llamada antes de recibir la peticion, deberias llamar a la funcion dentro del cuerpo del try, para saberlo coloca un consolo.log que alguna frase en el try y otro luego de la llamada a la funcion y ve cual se imprime primero

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, pero aparentemente ese no es el error e intentado diversas formas para renderizar la propiedad, realicé un setTimeout con una demora de 4000ms y sigue dando undefined, realicé un condicional:  {datespoke.img !== undefined && (<p>{datespoke.img}</p>)} y nunca se renderizó la propiedad ya que  aparentemente su valor no se por que motivo es undefined , creo que me estoy equivocando al llamar la propiedad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay error en tu código, es solo que necesitas trabajar la respuesta de la Promesa con una funcion de continuación `then`:

```
let datespoke = GetPoke();
     console.log(datespoke); //informacion 
     console.log("img",datespoke.img); //undefined
     datespoke.then(response => {
       //aqui ya vez la estructura obj, dentro del scope de Home
       console.log("response",response);
 })
```

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426878/retornar-el-valor-de-una-promesa-y-alamacenarla-en-una-variable-en-reactjs/426904#426904), se explica un poco el uso de **Promesas** y la sintáxis `async/await` en el contexto `ReactJS`.

Recordemos que las funciones [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) regresan **Promesas**.

Por ùltimo, en functional programming para ReactJS, el patrón mas común para realizar solicitudes de datos a API's es usando el hook [useEffect](https://www.snippetsofhooks.dev/?inf_contact_key=44609561599b985044af9bfb163d30b7cc0558ed5d4c28cbfab114022b1ec50d):

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     let datespoke = GetPoke();
     console.log(datespoke); //informacion 
     console.log("img",datespoke.img); //undefined
     datespoke.then(response => {
       console.log("response",response);
     })
    },[])
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

[useEffect Doc oficial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: Gracias, se utiliza ese patrón porque aprovechamos que el componente se renderiza y hacemos la petición? podrias explicarme mejor porque se utiliza ese patrón (useefect)

Comment: Asi como tienes tu código, la `app` va a funcionar, pero observa que tienes repetidos los `console.log` 2 veces, esto significa que ReactJS esta haciendo doble regreso. Ahora cuando envuelves en `useEffect`, observa que Reactjs solo devuelve una vez la petición. Esto pasa porque `useEffect` esta configurado para  correr una vez, cuando el componente se haya montado totalmente; sugiero dar una revisada al concepto de `component lifecycle`, o lanzar otra pregunta para la comunidad relacionada al tema, será muy interesante ver lo que los colegas pueden aportar ya que es un tema muy solicitado.

Comment: Aquí [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380902/peticiones-react-js-hooks/380918#380918) relacionada al tema de `useEffect`, si consideras que fue de utilidad no olvides votar, saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias fíjate que ya voté tu respuesta, cualquier cosa avísame.