# React fetch de una URL y pintar los datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

Tengo un grid que muestra "N" productos y al hacer click en uno de ellos la idea es recibir una url del tipo http://localhost:3000/product/13-producto-de-pruebas

Donde "13" será el ID del producto y "producto de pruebas" formará parte de la URL.

La idea es este código de producto 13 recogerlo desde un componente en REACT y lanzar una consulta a la API de productos para devolver las propiedades del objeto y printarlas por pantalla.

Los problemas que me encuentro sin saber como resolver són :
a) donde actualmente tengo la constante termino = 13 , como recoger dicho valor de la URL? o debo pasarlo del componente anterior "grid" a este y recogerlo?
b) en el render del componente hago la llamada a la API, pues dicha API veo que se ejecuta infinita veces, solo quiero que lo haga una vez renderizado el componente.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Product extends Component{

state = {
    termino : '',
}


consultarApi = () => {
    const termino = 13;
    const url = `http://api-local.dev/api/products/${termino}`;
    console.log(url);

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({ productos : result } ));
}

datosBusqueda = (termino) => {
    this.setState({
        termino
    }, () => {
        this.consultarApi();
    })
}


render() {

    this.consultarApi();

    return (


            <div className="app container" style={{backgroundColor: "whitesmoke", padding: "10px"}}>

                Producto <br/><br/><br/><br/>

            </div>

    );
    }
}

export default Product;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) donde actualmente tengo la constante termino = 13 , como recoger dicho valor de la URL? o debo pasarlo del componente anterior "grid" a este y recogerlo?

Suponiendo que el componente `Grid` provee el `id(termino)`, entonces se puede pasar como props a `Producto`:

```
//pseudocodigo de grid
<Producto id={id}/>
```

> b) en el render del componente hago la llamada a la API, pues dicha API veo que se ejecuta infinita veces, solo quiero que lo haga una vez renderizado el componente.

Luego en `Producto`, el patrón más común es usar el método `componentDidMount` para hacer la llamada API, dentro de este scope se puede hacer uso de `id`, pues llega desde `Grid` como `props`:

```
//pseudocodigo de class Product
class Product extends Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state={
      productos:[]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      const url = `http://api-local.dev/api/products/${this.props.id}`;
      console.log(url);
  
      fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => this.setState({ productos : result } ));
  }
  
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="app container" style={{backgroundColor: "whitesmoke", padding: "10px"}}>
            Producto
            {/*Iterar sobre el estado this.state.productos */}
        </div>);
      }
  }
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias ahora lo he visto claro. 1000 gracias

Comment: Claro, se puede pensar el los componentes React como funciones JS  y las props como los parámetros que se pasan dicha función. Trata de revisar en cuanto puedas  a [React functional components](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363532/diferencia-entre-componente-y-elemento-de-react/363695#363695). Saludos